# trying to give players items every 5 mins but to only randomly 1 player if the room id is 20+

Tags: c#, random

getting problem in choosing player randomly.Error is cannot convert int to MyGame.player.
Any Suggestion what should i try to do ?

```
foreach (Player p in Players)
{
    if (PlayerCount == 20)
    {
        AddTimer(delegate
        {
            try
            {
               var lol = p;
               Random check = new Random();
               lol = check.Next(0, 20);                  
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
            { }
        }, 300000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you expect `lol = check.Next(0, 20);` to do.

Comment: trying to get a random Id from players.

Comment: The error is clear. You are trying to assign not value to player object. That's why you are seeing this error. You need to do `lol = Players[check.Next(0,20)];`

Comment: getting this error cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ienumberable'<player>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Random.Next](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx) has an `int` as return value :

> **Return Value**
>   Type: System.Int32
>   A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to minValue and less than maxValue; that is, the range of return values includes minValue but not maxValue. If minValue equals maxValue, minValue is returned.

You are trying to assign this value to an object of type `Player`. That's why the error.

up to now you are running through each player and choose a random number. If you want to have a random player you should use this number as index for your list:

```
Random check = new Random();
int randomIndex = check.Next(0, 20); 

Player randomPlayer = Players.ElementAt(randomIndex)
randomPlayer.ID = // <- here your ID
```

Comment: i am getting this error cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ienumberable'<player>

Comment: @Kiyo ok then try please: `Players.ElementAt(randomIndex)` or `Players.ToList()(randomIndex]`

Comment: I clicked the green tick. Cause i Cant click as Answer is useful cause dont have sufficient reputation .